# List of ID from confusion matrix in R

Tags: r, correlation, confusion-matrix

I have a little question. Actually I use dataset from UCI with information about cancer in Wisconsin. How can I take information (ID) from confusion matrix in R? If I have information about amount of people which have a concrete type of cancer, I must have information about their id. Here is my code:

**breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt**

```
1000025,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1002945,5,4,4,5,7,10,3,2,1,2
1015425,3,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2
1016277,6,8,8,1,3,4,3,7,1,2
1017023,4,1,1,3,2,1,3,1,1,2
1017122,8,10,10,8,7,10,9,7,1,4
1018099,1,1,1,1,2,10,3,1,1,2
1018561,2,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1033078,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,5,2
1033078,4,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1035283,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1036172,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1041801,5,3,3,3,2,3,4,4,1,4
1043999,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,2
1044572,8,7,5,10,7,9,5,5,4,4
1047630,7,4,6,4,6,1,4,3,1,4
1048672,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1049815,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1050670,10,7,7,6,4,10,4,1,2,4
1050718,6,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1054590,7,3,2,10,5,10,5,4,4,4
1054593,10,5,5,3,6,7,7,10,1,4
1056784,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1057013,8,4,5,1,2,NA,7,3,1,4
1059552,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1065726,5,2,3,4,2,7,3,6,1,4
1066373,3,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1066979,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1067444,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1070935,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1070935,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1071760,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1072179,10,7,7,3,8,5,7,4,3,4
1074610,2,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,1,2
1075123,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1079304,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1080185,10,10,10,8,6,1,8,9,1,4
1081791,6,2,1,1,1,1,7,1,1,2
1084584,5,4,4,9,2,10,5,6,1,4
1091262,2,5,3,3,6,7,7,5,1,4
1096800,6,6,6,9,6,NA,7,8,1,2
1099510,10,4,3,1,3,3,6,5,2,4
1100524,6,10,10,2,8,10,7,3,3,4
1102573,5,6,5,6,10,1,3,1,1,4
1103608,10,10,10,4,8,1,8,10,1,4
1103722,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2
1105257,3,7,7,4,4,9,4,8,1,4
1105524,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1106095,4,1,1,3,2,1,3,1,1,2
1106829,7,8,7,2,4,8,3,8,2,4
1108370,9,5,8,1,2,3,2,1,5,4
1108449,5,3,3,4,2,4,3,4,1,4
1110102,10,3,6,2,3,5,4,10,2,4
1110503,5,5,5,8,10,8,7,3,7,4
1110524,10,5,5,6,8,8,7,1,1,4
1111249,10,6,6,3,4,5,3,6,1,4
1112209,8,10,10,1,3,6,3,9,1,4
1113038,8,2,4,1,5,1,5,4,4,4
1113483,5,2,3,1,6,10,5,1,1,4
1113906,9,5,5,2,2,2,5,1,1,4
1115282,5,3,5,5,3,3,4,10,1,4
1115293,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2
1116116,9,10,10,1,10,8,3,3,1,4
1116132,6,3,4,1,5,2,3,9,1,4
1116192,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1116998,10,4,2,1,3,2,4,3,10,4
1117152,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1118039,5,3,4,1,8,10,4,9,1,4
1120559,8,3,8,3,4,9,8,9,8,4
1121732,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,2
1121919,5,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1123061,6,10,2,8,10,2,7,8,10,4
1124651,1,3,3,2,2,1,7,2,1,2
1125035,9,4,5,10,6,10,4,8,1,4
1126417,10,6,4,1,3,4,3,2,3,4
1131294,1,1,2,1,2,2,4,2,1,2
1132347,1,1,4,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1133041,5,3,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2
1133136,3,1,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,2
1136142,2,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,2
1137156,2,2,2,1,1,1,7,1,1,2
1143978,4,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2
1143978,5,2,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1147044,3,1,1,1,2,2,7,1,1,2
1147699,3,5,7,8,8,9,7,10,7,4
1147748,5,10,6,1,10,4,4,10,10,4
1148278,3,3,6,4,5,8,4,4,1,4
1148873,3,6,6,6,5,10,6,8,3,4
1152331,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1155546,2,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2
1156272,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1156948,3,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2
1157734,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1158247,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1160476,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1164066,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1165297,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2
1165790,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1165926,9,6,9,2,10,6,2,9,10,4
1166630,7,5,6,10,5,10,7,9,4,4
1166654,10,3,5,1,10,5,3,10,2,4
1167439,2,3,4,4,2,5,2,5,1,4
1167471,4,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1168359,8,2,3,1,6,3,7,1,1,4
1168736,10,10,10,10,10,1,8,8,8,4
1169049,7,3,4,4,3,3,3,2,7,4
1170419,10,10,10,8,2,10,4,1,1,4
1170420,1,6,8,10,8,10,5,7,1,4
1171710,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2
1171710,6,5,4,4,3,9,7,8,3,4
1171795,1,3,1,2,2,2,5,3,2,2
1171845,8,6,4,3,5,9,3,1,1,4
1172152,10,3,3,10,2,10,7,3,3,4
1173216,10,10,10,3,10,8,8,1,1,4
1173235,3,3,2,1,2,3,3,1,1,2
1173347,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,2
1173347,8,3,3,1,2,2,3,2,1,2
1173509,4,5,5,10,4,10,7,5,8,4
1173514,1,1,1,1,4,3,1,1,1,2
1173681,3,2,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2
1174057,1,1,2,2,2,1,3,1,1,2
1174057,4,2,1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2
1174131,10,10,10,2,10,10,5,3,3,4
1174428,5,3,5,1,8,10,5,3,1,4
1175937,5,4,6,7,9,7,8,10,1,4
1176406,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1176881,7,5,3,7,4,10,7,5,5,4
1177027,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1177399,8,3,5,4,5,10,1,6,2,4
1177512,1,1,1,1,10,1,1,1,1,2
1178580,5,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1179818,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1180194,5,10,8,10,8,10,3,6,3,4
1180523,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2
1180831,3,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,2
1181356,5,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,2
1182404,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1182410,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1183240,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1183246,1,1,1,1,1,NA,2,1,1,2
1183516,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1183911,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1183983,9,5,5,4,4,5,4,3,3,4
1184184,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,2
1184241,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1184840,1,1,3,1,2,NA,2,1,1,2
1185609,3,4,5,2,6,8,4,1,1,4
1185610,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,1,1,2
1187457,3,1,1,3,8,1,5,8,1,2
1187805,8,8,7,4,10,10,7,8,7,4
1188472,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1189266,7,2,4,1,6,10,5,4,3,4
1189286,10,10,8,6,4,5,8,10,1,4
1190394,4,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,2
1190485,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1192325,5,5,5,6,3,10,3,1,1,4
1193091,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1193210,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1193683,1,1,2,1,3,NA,1,1,1,2
1196295,9,9,10,3,6,10,7,10,6,4
1196915,10,7,7,4,5,10,5,7,2,4
1197080,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,2
1197270,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1197440,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,7,2
1197510,5,1,1,1,2,NA,3,1,1,2
1197979,4,1,1,1,2,2,3,2,1,2
1197993,5,6,7,8,8,10,3,10,3,4
1198128,10,8,10,10,6,1,3,1,10,4
1198641,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1199219,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2
1199731,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1199983,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1200772,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1200847,6,10,10,10,8,10,10,10,7,4
1200892,8,6,5,4,3,10,6,1,1,4
1200952,5,8,7,7,10,10,5,7,1,4
1201834,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1201936,5,10,10,3,8,1,5,10,3,4
1202125,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1202812,5,3,3,3,6,10,3,1,1,4
1203096,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1204242,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1204898,6,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1205138,5,8,8,8,5,10,7,8,1,4
1205579,8,7,6,4,4,10,5,1,1,4
1206089,2,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1206695,1,5,8,6,5,8,7,10,1,4
1206841,10,5,6,10,6,10,7,7,10,4
1207986,5,8,4,10,5,8,9,10,1,4
1208301,1,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1210963,10,10,10,8,6,8,7,10,1,4
1211202,7,5,10,10,10,10,4,10,3,4
1212232,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1212251,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1212422,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1212422,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1213375,8,4,4,5,4,7,7,8,2,2
1213383,5,1,1,4,2,1,3,1,1,2
1214092,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1214556,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1214966,9,7,7,5,5,10,7,8,3,4
1216694,10,8,8,4,10,10,8,1,1,4
1216947,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1217051,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1217264,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1218105,5,10,10,9,6,10,7,10,5,4
1218741,10,10,9,3,7,5,3,5,1,4
1218860,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1218860,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1219406,5,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1219525,8,10,10,10,5,10,8,10,6,4
1219859,8,10,8,8,4,8,7,7,1,4
1220330,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1221863,10,10,10,10,7,10,7,10,4,4
1222047,10,10,10,10,3,10,10,6,1,4
1222936,8,7,8,7,5,5,5,10,2,4
1223282,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1223426,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1223793,6,10,7,7,6,4,8,10,2,4
1223967,6,1,3,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1224329,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,1,2
1225799,10,6,4,3,10,10,9,10,1,4
1226012,4,1,1,3,1,5,2,1,1,4
1226612,7,5,6,3,3,8,7,4,1,4
1227210,10,5,5,6,3,10,7,9,2,4
1227244,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1227481,10,5,7,4,4,10,8,9,1,4
1228152,8,9,9,5,3,5,7,7,1,4
1228311,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1230175,10,10,10,3,10,10,9,10,1,4
1230688,7,4,7,4,3,7,7,6,1,4
1231387,6,8,7,5,6,8,8,9,2,4
1231706,8,4,6,3,3,1,4,3,1,2
1232225,10,4,5,5,5,10,4,1,1,4
1236043,3,3,2,1,3,1,3,6,1,2
1241232,3,1,4,1,2,NA,3,1,1,2
1241559,10,8,8,2,8,10,4,8,10,4
1241679,9,8,8,5,6,2,4,10,4,4
1242364,8,10,10,8,6,9,3,10,10,4
1243256,10,4,3,2,3,10,5,3,2,4
1270479,5,1,3,3,2,2,2,3,1,2
1276091,3,1,1,3,1,1,3,1,1,2
1277018,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
128059,1,1,1,1,2,5,5,1,1,2
1285531,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1287775,5,1,1,2,2,2,3,1,1,2
144888,8,10,10,8,5,10,7,8,1,4
145447,8,4,4,1,2,9,3,3,1,4
167528,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,6,1,2
169356,3,1,1,1,2,NA,3,1,1,2
183913,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
191250,10,4,4,10,2,10,5,3,3,4
1017023,6,3,3,5,3,10,3,5,3,2
1100524,6,10,10,2,8,10,7,3,3,4
1116116,9,10,10,1,10,8,3,3,1,4
1168736,5,6,6,2,4,10,3,6,1,4
1182404,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1182404,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1198641,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
242970,5,7,7,1,5,8,3,4,1,2
255644,10,5,8,10,3,10,5,1,3,4
263538,5,10,10,6,10,10,10,6,5,4
274137,8,8,9,4,5,10,7,8,1,4
303213,10,4,4,10,6,10,5,5,1,4
314428,7,9,4,10,10,3,5,3,3,4
1182404,5,1,4,1,2,1,3,2,1,2
1198641,10,10,6,3,3,10,4,3,2,4
320675,3,3,5,2,3,10,7,1,1,4
324427,10,8,8,2,3,4,8,7,8,4
385103,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
390840,8,4,7,1,3,10,3,9,2,4
411453,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
320675,3,3,5,2,3,10,7,1,1,4
428903,7,2,4,1,3,4,3,3,1,4
431495,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,2
432809,3,1,3,1,2,NA,2,1,1,2
434518,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
452264,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
456282,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
476903,10,5,7,3,3,7,3,3,8,4
486283,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
486662,2,1,1,2,2,1,3,1,1,2
488173,1,4,3,10,4,10,5,6,1,4
492268,10,4,6,1,2,10,5,3,1,4
508234,7,4,5,10,2,10,3,8,2,4
527363,8,10,10,10,8,10,10,7,3,4
529329,10,10,10,10,10,10,4,10,10,4
535331,3,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,2
543558,6,1,3,1,4,5,5,10,1,4
555977,5,6,6,8,6,10,4,10,4,4
560680,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
561477,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
563649,8,8,8,1,2,NA,6,10,1,4
601265,10,4,4,6,2,10,2,3,1,4
606140,1,1,1,1,2,NA,2,1,1,2
606722,5,5,7,8,6,10,7,4,1,4
616240,5,3,4,3,4,5,4,7,1,2
61634,5,4,3,1,2,NA,2,3,1,2
625201,8,2,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,2
63375,9,1,2,6,4,10,7,7,2,4
635844,8,4,10,5,4,4,7,10,1,4
636130,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
640744,10,10,10,7,9,10,7,10,10,4
646904,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
653777,8,3,4,9,3,10,3,3,1,4
659642,10,8,4,4,4,10,3,10,4,4
666090,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
666942,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
667204,7,8,7,6,4,3,8,8,4,4
673637,3,1,1,1,2,5,5,1,1,2
684955,2,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,2
688033,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
691628,8,6,4,10,10,1,3,5,1,4
693702,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
704097,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
704168,4,6,5,6,7,NA,4,9,1,2
706426,5,5,5,2,5,10,4,3,1,4
709287,6,8,7,8,6,8,8,9,1,4
718641,1,1,1,1,5,1,3,1,1,2
721482,4,4,4,4,6,5,7,3,1,2
730881,7,6,3,2,5,10,7,4,6,4
733639,3,1,1,1,2,NA,3,1,1,2
733639,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
733823,5,4,6,10,2,10,4,1,1,4
740492,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
743348,3,2,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,2
752904,10,1,1,1,2,10,5,4,1,4
756136,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
760001,8,10,3,2,6,4,3,10,1,4
760239,10,4,6,4,5,10,7,1,1,4
76389,10,4,7,2,2,8,6,1,1,4
764974,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,2,2
770066,5,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2
785208,5,4,6,6,4,10,4,3,1,4
785615,8,6,7,3,3,10,3,4,2,4
792744,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
797327,6,5,5,8,4,10,3,4,1,4
798429,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
704097,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
806423,8,5,5,5,2,10,4,3,1,4
809912,10,3,3,1,2,10,7,6,1,4
810104,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
814265,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
814911,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
822829,7,6,4,8,10,10,9,5,3,4
826923,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
830690,5,2,2,2,3,1,1,3,1,2
831268,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,2
832226,3,4,4,10,5,1,3,3,1,4
832567,4,2,3,5,3,8,7,6,1,4
836433,5,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
837082,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
846832,3,4,5,3,7,3,4,6,1,2
850831,2,7,10,10,7,10,4,9,4,4
855524,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
857774,4,1,1,1,3,1,2,2,1,2
859164,5,3,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,4
859350,8,10,10,7,10,10,7,3,8,4
866325,8,10,5,3,8,4,4,10,3,4
873549,10,3,5,4,3,7,3,5,3,4
877291,6,10,10,10,10,10,8,10,10,4
877943,3,10,3,10,6,10,5,1,4,4
888169,3,2,2,1,4,3,2,1,1,2
888523,4,4,4,2,2,3,2,1,1,2
896404,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
897172,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
95719,6,10,10,10,8,10,7,10,7,4
160296,5,8,8,10,5,10,8,10,3,4
342245,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
428598,1,1,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
492561,4,3,2,1,3,1,2,1,1,2
493452,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
493452,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
521441,5,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2
560680,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
636437,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
640712,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
654244,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
657753,3,1,1,4,3,1,2,2,1,2
685977,5,3,4,1,4,1,3,1,1,2
805448,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
846423,10,6,3,6,4,10,7,8,4,4
1002504,3,2,2,2,2,1,3,2,1,2
1022257,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1026122,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1071084,3,3,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,2
1080233,7,6,6,3,2,10,7,1,1,4
1114570,5,3,3,2,3,1,3,1,1,2
1114570,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2
1116715,5,1,1,1,3,2,2,2,1,2
1131411,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2
1151734,10,8,7,4,3,10,7,9,1,4
1156017,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1158247,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1158405,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1168278,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1176187,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1196263,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1196475,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2
1206314,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1211265,3,10,8,7,6,9,9,3,8,4
1213784,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1223003,5,3,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1223306,3,1,1,1,2,4,1,1,1,2
1223543,1,2,1,3,2,1,1,2,1,2
1229929,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1231853,4,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1234554,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1236837,2,3,2,2,2,2,3,1,1,2
1237674,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1238021,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1238464,1,1,1,1,1,NA,2,1,1,2
1238633,10,10,10,6,8,4,8,5,1,4
1238915,5,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1238948,8,5,6,2,3,10,6,6,1,4
1239232,3,3,2,6,3,3,3,5,1,2
1239347,8,7,8,5,10,10,7,2,1,4
1239967,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1240337,5,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2
1253505,2,3,1,1,5,1,1,1,1,2
1255384,3,2,2,3,2,3,3,1,1,2
1257200,10,10,10,7,10,10,8,2,1,4
1257648,4,3,3,1,2,1,3,3,1,2
1257815,5,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1257938,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1258549,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,1,4
1258556,5,3,6,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1266154,8,7,8,2,4,2,5,10,1,4
1272039,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1276091,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1276091,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2
1276091,5,1,1,3,4,1,3,2,1,2
1277629,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2
1293439,3,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
1293439,6,9,7,5,5,8,4,2,1,2
1294562,10,8,10,1,3,10,5,1,1,4
1295186,10,10,10,1,6,1,2,8,1,4
527337,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
558538,4,1,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
566509,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
608157,10,4,3,10,4,10,10,1,1,4
677910,5,2,2,4,2,4,1,1,1,2
734111,1,1,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,2
734111,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2
780555,5,1,1,6,3,1,2,1,1,2
827627,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1049837,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1058849,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1182404,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1193544,5,7,9,8,6,10,8,10,1,4
1201870,4,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,2
1202253,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1227081,3,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
1230994,4,5,5,8,6,10,10,7,1,4
1238410,2,3,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,2
1246562,10,2,2,1,2,6,1,1,2,4
1257470,10,6,5,8,5,10,8,6,1,4
1259008,8,8,9,6,6,3,10,10,1,4
1266124,5,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1267898,5,1,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1268313,5,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
1268804,3,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,2
1276091,6,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
1280258,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2
1293966,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1296572,10,9,8,7,6,4,7,10,3,4
1298416,10,6,6,2,4,10,9,7,1,4
1299596,6,6,6,5,4,10,7,6,2,4
1105524,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1181685,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1211594,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1238777,6,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
1257608,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1269574,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1277145,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1287282,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1296025,4,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1296263,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1296593,5,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1299161,4,8,7,10,4,10,7,5,1,4
1301945,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1302428,5,3,2,4,2,1,1,1,1,2
1318169,9,10,10,10,10,5,10,10,10,4
474162,8,7,8,5,5,10,9,10,1,4
787451,5,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1002025,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,1,2
1070522,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1073960,10,10,10,10,6,10,8,1,5,4
1076352,3,6,4,10,3,3,3,4,1,4
1084139,6,3,2,1,3,4,4,1,1,4
1115293,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1119189,5,8,9,4,3,10,7,1,1,4
1133991,4,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1142706,5,10,10,10,6,10,6,5,2,4
1155967,5,1,2,10,4,5,2,1,1,2
1170945,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1181567,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1182404,4,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1204558,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1217952,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1224565,6,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1238186,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1253917,4,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2
1265899,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1268766,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1277268,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1286943,8,10,10,10,7,5,4,8,7,4
1295508,1,1,1,1,2,4,1,1,1,2
1297327,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1297522,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1298360,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1299924,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1299994,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1304595,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1306282,6,6,7,10,3,10,8,10,2,4
1313325,4,10,4,7,3,10,9,10,1,4
1320077,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1320077,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1320304,3,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2
1330439,4,7,8,3,4,10,9,1,1,4
333093,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,2
369565,4,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,2
412300,10,4,5,4,3,5,7,3,1,4
672113,7,5,6,10,4,10,5,3,1,4
749653,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
769612,3,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2
769612,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
798429,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
807657,6,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,2
8233704,4,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
837480,7,4,4,3,4,10,6,9,1,4
867392,4,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
869828,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,2
1043068,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1056171,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1061990,1,1,3,2,2,1,3,1,1,2
1113061,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1116192,5,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1135090,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1145420,6,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1158157,5,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2
1171578,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1174841,5,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1184586,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1186936,2,1,3,2,2,1,2,1,1,2
1197527,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1222464,6,10,10,10,4,10,7,10,1,4
1240603,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1240603,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1241035,7,8,3,7,4,5,7,8,2,4
1287971,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1289391,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1299924,3,2,2,2,2,1,4,2,1,2
1306339,4,4,2,1,2,5,2,1,2,2
1313658,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1313982,4,3,1,1,2,1,4,8,1,2
1321264,5,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2
1321321,5,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
1321348,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1321931,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1321942,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1321942,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1328331,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1328755,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1331405,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,2
1331412,5,7,10,10,5,10,10,10,1,4
1333104,3,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1334071,4,1,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,2
1343068,8,4,4,1,6,10,2,5,2,4
1343374,10,10,8,10,6,5,10,3,1,4
1344121,8,10,4,4,8,10,8,2,1,4
142932,7,6,10,5,3,10,9,10,2,4
183936,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
324382,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
378275,10,9,7,3,4,2,7,7,1,4
385103,5,1,2,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
690557,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
695091,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
695219,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
824249,1,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
871549,5,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
878358,5,7,10,6,5,10,7,5,1,4
1107684,6,10,5,5,4,10,6,10,1,4
1115762,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1217717,5,1,1,6,3,1,1,1,1,2
1239420,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1254538,8,10,10,10,6,10,10,10,1,4
1261751,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2
1268275,9,8,8,9,6,3,4,1,1,4
1272166,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1294261,4,10,8,5,4,1,10,1,1,4
1295529,2,5,7,6,4,10,7,6,1,4
1298484,10,3,4,5,3,10,4,1,1,4
1311875,5,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1315506,4,8,6,3,4,10,7,1,1,4
1320141,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1325309,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1333063,5,1,3,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1333495,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1334659,5,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,2
1336798,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1344449,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1350568,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1352663,5,4,6,8,4,1,8,10,1,4
188336,5,3,2,8,5,10,8,1,2,4
352431,10,5,10,3,5,8,7,8,3,4
353098,4,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2
411453,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
557583,5,10,10,10,10,10,10,1,1,4
636375,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
736150,10,4,3,10,3,10,7,1,2,4
803531,5,10,10,10,5,2,8,5,1,4
822829,8,10,10,10,6,10,10,10,10,4
1016634,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1031608,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2
1041043,4,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1042252,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1057067,1,1,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,2
1061990,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1073836,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1083817,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1096352,6,3,3,3,3,2,6,1,1,2
1140597,7,1,2,3,2,1,2,1,1,2
1149548,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1174009,5,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2
1183596,3,1,3,1,3,4,1,1,1,2
1190386,4,6,6,5,7,6,7,7,3,4
1190546,2,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,2
1213273,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1218982,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1225382,6,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1235807,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1238777,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1253955,8,7,4,4,5,3,5,10,1,4
1257366,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1260659,3,1,4,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1268952,10,10,7,8,7,1,10,10,3,4
1275807,4,2,4,3,2,2,2,1,1,2
1277792,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1277792,5,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
1285722,4,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
1288608,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1290203,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1294413,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1299596,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1303489,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1311033,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1311108,1,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
1315807,5,10,10,10,10,2,10,10,10,4
1318671,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1319609,3,1,1,2,3,4,1,1,1,2
1323477,1,2,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,2
1324572,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2
1324681,4,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1325159,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1326892,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1330361,5,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1333877,5,4,5,1,8,1,3,6,1,2
1334015,7,8,8,7,3,10,7,2,3,4
1334667,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1339781,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1339781,4,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
13454352,1,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1345452,1,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1345593,3,1,1,3,2,1,2,1,1,2
1347749,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1347943,5,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2
1348851,3,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1350319,5,7,4,1,6,1,7,10,3,4
1350423,5,10,10,8,5,5,7,10,1,4
1352848,3,10,7,8,5,8,7,4,1,4
1353092,3,2,1,2,2,1,3,1,1,2
1354840,2,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,1,2
1354840,5,3,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,2
1355260,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1365075,4,1,4,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1365328,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2
1368267,5,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1368273,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1368882,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
1369821,10,10,10,10,5,10,10,10,7,4
1371026,5,10,10,10,4,10,5,6,3,4
1371920,5,1,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,2
466906,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
466906,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
534555,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
536708,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
566346,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2
603148,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
654546,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,8,2
654546,1,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,1,2
695091,5,10,10,5,4,5,4,4,1,4
714039,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
763235,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2
776715,3,1,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,2
841769,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2
888820,5,10,10,3,7,3,8,10,2,4
897471,4,8,6,4,3,4,10,6,1,4
897471,4,8,8,5,4,5,10,4,1,4
```

And my code:

```
library(plyr)
library(mlbench)
library(class)
library(rpart)
library(caret)
library(FSelector)
library(MASS)
library(gdata)
library(corrplot)
library(nnet)
library(adabag)
library(neuralnet)

k=10
set.seed(k)
data_biopsy <-read.table("breast-cancer-wisconsin.data.txt",sep = ",")
data_biopsy <- data.frame(data_biopsy)
data_biopsy <- na.omit(data_biopsy)
data_biopsy$V11 = as.factor(data_biopsy$V11)
x = as.matrix(data_biopsy[,names(data_biopsy) != "V11"])

data_biopsy[,names(data_biopsy) != "V11"] <-x

data_biopsy$id <- sample(1:k, nrow(data_biopsy), replace = TRUE)
list <- 1:k

CorMat <- cor(data_biopsy[,names(data_biopsy) != "V11"])
CorMat
corrplot(CorMat)
corrplot(CorMat, order = "hclust")

accuracies_nn15 <- vector("numeric")

final_accuracy_nn=0
progress.bar <- create_progress_bar("text")

#Neural Network
progress.bar$init(k)
for (i in 1:k)
{
  trainingset <- subset(data_biopsy, id %in% list[-i])
  testset <- subset(data_biopsy, id %in% c(i))

  trainingset <- trainingset[,names(trainingset) != "id"]
  testset <- testset[,names(testset) != "id"]

  neural_network15 <- nnet(V11~. , data = trainingset, size=5, maxit = 1000, decay = 1.5)

  pred.neural_network15 <- predict(neural_network15,testset,type = "class")
  fold_accuracy_nn15 <- mean(pred.neural_network15 == testset$V11)

  matrix_nn15 <-as.table(confusionMatrix(pred.neural_network15, testset$V11))

  accuracies_nn15 <- append(accuracies_nn15, fold_accuracy_nn15)

  progress.bar$step()
}

print("Table for k-fold cross validation:")
accuracies_nn15*100

print("Average efficiency:")
final_accuracy_nn <- mean(accuracies_nn15)
final_accuracy_nn*100

print("Last confusion matrix:")
matrix_nn15

"BOXPLOT"
acc_mat <- matrix(c(accuracies_nn15*100), nrow=length(accuracies_nn15*100))
colnames(acc_mat) <- c("Neural Network")
boxplot(acc_mat,ylab ="Accuracy [%]",las = 1,cex.axis = 1)

"DOTPLOT"
dotplot(acc_mat,xlab ="Accuracy [%]",ylab="Validation", col = c("orange"), pch = 15)
legend( x= "topleft",legend = c("Neural network"), col = c("orange"), pch = 15)

"Neural network"
trainingset$V11 = as.numeric(trainingset$V11)
n <- names(trainingset)
f <- as.formula(paste("V11 ~", paste(n[!n %in% "V11"], collapse = " + ")))
nn <- neuralnet(f,data=trainingset,hidden=c(5,3), act.fct = "logistic", linear.output=TRUE,lifesign = "minimal")
plot(nn)
```

Result of 10 validation

```
> matrix_nn15
          Reference
Prediction  2  4
         2 40  0
         4  1 23
```

Efficiency: 63/64 = 98,44%. Forty people from testset have benign type of cancer, twenty three have malignant type. I need IDs this twenty four people which need help from doctor. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's easier to help you when you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run and test the code. Ideally you'd use some built-in data set in your example or include a `dput()` in your question

Comment: I corrected the first post @MrFlick :)